# Share a method between two child components (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There is such structure of components:

[image]

**Desired Behavior**

`child1_component` - is a header.

`child2_component` - is a body.

There is a button inside `child1_component`.

Clicking on that button I want to invoke a method inside `child2_component`.

**Question**

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this would be to use a service with rxjs subjects and observables.

1. When the user clicks on the button in child1_component then it calls a method that in turn calls a method inside the shared service.
2. When the method in the service is called it can emit a value as an observable via a subject.
3. child2_component then subscribes to the observable within the shared service and can operate some logic based on when it receives data from the service.

More on services here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Great tutorial on subjects and rxjs: https://blog.angulartraining.com/rxjs-subjects-a-tutorial-4dcce0e9637f

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1.Service:

```
    export class ActionService {
      private someAction = new Subject();


      someActionEmitted$(): Observable<unknown> {
        return this.someAction.asObservable();
      }

      emitSomeAction(): void {
        this.someAction.next();
      }
    }


    //childComponent1
    export class ChildComponent1 {
      constructor(private actionService: ActionService) {
      }

      emitAction(): void {
        this.actionService.emitSomeAction();
      }
    }

    //childComponent2
    export class ChildComponent2 implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      private destroy$ = new Subject();

      constructor(private actionService: ActionService) {
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.actionService.someActionEmitted$()
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))  // dont forget to unsubscribe, can cause memory leaks
          .subscribe(() => this.doSomething());
      }

      doSomething(): void {
        // your logic here
      }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
      }
    }
```

2. Using Parent Component

`<child-component1 (btnClicked)="childComponentBtnClick()"></child-component1>
 <child-component2 [clickBtnSubject]="childBtnClicked"></child-component1>`

Ts logic:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  childBtnClicked = new Subject();

  childComponentBtnClick(): void {
    this.childBtnClicked.next();
  }
}


//childComponent1
export class ChildComponent1 {
  @Output() btnClicked = new EventEmitter();


  emitAction(): void {
    this.btnClicked.emit(); // you can pass value to emit() method
  }
}

//childComponent2
export class ChildComponent2 implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() clickBtnSubject: Subject;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clickBtnSubject
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))  // dont forget to unsubscribe, can cause memory leaks
      .subscribe(() => this.doSomething());
  }

  doSomething(): void {
    // your logic here
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: From parent you has access to all the properties/method of his children using a template variable reference or Viewchild

Answer (score 0):

On your general.component.html :

```
<app-child1 (clicked)="app1Clicked($event)"></app-child1>

<app-child2 #child2></app-child2>
```

On your general.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('child2', {static: true}) child2: Child2Component;

app1Clicked($event) {
   this.child2.doSomething()
}
```

On the child1.components.ts:

```
@Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

onClick() {
 this.clicked.emit();
}
```

Finally on the child2.component.ts:

```
doSomething() {
 alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: I believe it's bad practise using ViewChild to call component method

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: сould be hard to testing, if some other components will need to listen this action,too?:) 
In any way, I don't prefer this method

Comment: Ok thanks it stands ;) I think your method with Subject is a good way to do it.